# How to read, edit and export word documents in WPF without Microsoft office being installed?

Tags: wpf, ms-word

I have an WPF application that relies heavily on manipulating documents; I want to know if there is a library that works independetly from Microsoft Office Word and that provides the following features:

- Reading word documents (*.doc or rtf will be suffisiant, *.docx will be perfect)
- Enable me to edit the document from my WPF app
- Enable me to export again the document into other formats (word, excel, pdf)
- Free :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK last option is incompatible with others, sorry.

Comment: You may also take a look at this answer on Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025737/how-to-create-a-report-generator-in-word

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer in order:

- Reading: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-File-in-WPF) is good for you.
- Edit & export: May be [this library](https://documenteditor.codeplex.com/) works for you.
- Free: The most difficult part of your question. You can do it for free using [Interop Assemblies for Office](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36432/Edit-Microsoft-Word-Document-From-Your-Application). But controls for free... Many controls not free around the net.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for the reply, after googling I ends up that there is not a lot of free solutions for word processing! I think I will use the rtf format!

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with similar question some years ago. I had Windows forms application with some 20 reports and about 100 users and I needed to generate Word documents from application. Application was installed on a server. My first attempt was done by using Office interop, but it caused problems with performance and all kinds of unpredictable exceptions. So I started to look for alternatives and I soon landed with OpenXML.

First idea was that our team would use OpenXML SDK to generate and manipulate documents. It soon turned out that the learning curve was way too steep and our management wasn't willing to pay for the extra work.

So we started to look for alternatives. We didn't find any useful free library and so we tried some commercial ones (Aspose, Docentric). Aspose gave great results, but it was too expensive. Docentric's license is cheaper and the product performed well in Word document generation, so we finally decided to purchase it.

**WHAT IT TAKES TO GENERATE A DOCUMENT FROM A TEMPLATE**

1. Install Docentric Toolkit (you can get 30 day trial version for free)
2. In your VisualStudio project ad references to 4 Docentric dlls, which you can find in installation folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Docentric\Toolkit\Bin
3. Include Entity Framework via NuGet package If you will fill data from SQL database into the Word document
4. Prepare Word template, where you define layout and include fields which will get filled with data at document generation (see on-line documentation how to do it).

It doesn't take much code to prepare the data to be merged with the template. In my example I prepare order for customer "BONAP" from Northwind database. Orders include customer data, order details and product data. Data model also includes header and footer data.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Docentric.Word;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace WordReporting
    {
        // Report data model
        public class ReportData
        {
            public ReportData()
            { }

            public string headerReportTemplatetName { get; set; }
            public string footerDateCreated { get; set; }
            public string footerUserName { get; set; }
            public List<Order> reportDetails { get; set; }
        }


        // model extensions

        public partial class Order
        {
            public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Order_Detail
        {
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        }


        // Main
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // variable declaration
                List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
                string templateName = @"c:\temp\Orders_template1.docx";
                string generatedDocument = @"c:\temp\Orders_result.docx";

                // reading data from database
                using (var ctx = new NorthwindEntities1())
                {
                    orderList = ctx.Orders
                        .Include("Customer")
                        .Include("Order_Details")
                        .Include("Order_Details.Product")
                        .Where(q => q.CustomerID == "BONAP").ToList();
                }

                // collecting data for the report
                ReportData repData = new ReportData();

                repData.headerReportTemplatetName = templateName;
                repData.footerUserName = "<user name comes here>";
                repData.footerDateCreated = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                repData.reportDetails = new List<Order>();

                foreach (var o in orderList)
                {
                    Order tempOrder = new Order();
                    tempOrder.Customer = new Customer();

                    tempOrder.OrderID = o.OrderID;
                    tempOrder.Customer.CompanyName = o.Customer.CompanyName;
                    tempOrder.Customer.Address = o.Customer.Address;
                    tempOrder.Customer.City = o.Customer.City;
                    tempOrder.Customer.Country = o.Customer.Country;
                    tempOrder.OrderDate = o.OrderDate;
                    tempOrder.ShippedDate = o.ShippedDate;

                    foreach (Order_Detail od in o.Order_Details)
                    {
                        Order_Detail tempOrderDetail = new Order_Detail();
                        tempOrderDetail.Product = new Product();

                        tempOrderDetail.OrderID = od.OrderID;
                        tempOrderDetail.ProductID = od.ProductID;
                        tempOrderDetail.Product.ProductName = od.Product.ProductName;
                        tempOrderDetail.UnitPrice = od.UnitPrice;
                        tempOrderDetail.Quantity = od.Quantity;

                        tempOrderDetail.Amount = od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity;
                        tempOrder.TotalAmount = tempOrder.TotalAmount + tempOrderDetail.Amount;

                        tempOrder.Order_Details.Add(tempOrderDetail);
                    }

                    repData.reportDetails.Add(tempOrder);
                }

                try
                {
                    // Word document generation
                    DocumentGenerator dg = new DocumentGenerator(repData);
                    DocumentGenerationResult result = dg.GenerateDocument(templateName, generatedDocument);

                    // start MS Word and show generated document
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + generatedDocument + "\"";
                    Process.Start(startInfo);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                // wait for the input to terminate the application
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```